# How do I do advanced search query using "OR" in solr dismax

Tags: solr, edismax, dismax

How can you specify a query like "java with (developer OR programmer)" using solr dismax handler...

It works with solr standard handler but not with dismax

Answer (score 2):

The default for dismax is OR (optional), and if you want terms to be mandatory you must add a plus-sign in front of them. So assuming your query must contain "java with" something like "+java +with developer programmer" should work.

The mm is used to set the number of optional clauses that must match. Default is 100%, so this will probably need some tweaking to give the result you want. There are some examples to be found [here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/util/doc-files/min-should-match.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that dismax is not designed to handle such queries. Dismax supports a simplified version of the Lucene QueryParser syntax. When using it, it allows the users only to provide keywords and not to bother with syntax.

You can find more [details about dismax here](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/05/23/whats-a-dismax/). Pay attention to the part about the mm parameter that allows to simulate boolean queries with dismax.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a little off topic but it seems here that the programmer and developer words are synonyms and best if placed in the synonyms file, effectively neutralizing the need for a "programmer or developer" type of statement.  Otherwise, tweaking the minimum should match is the closest thing.  The best route to go would be to switch to a new version of solr with EDISMAX since that'll support the standard and dismax syntax.